# How do i parse lines with leading spaces

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am very new to Grep and regular expressions. From below text output, how can I get list groups. I just want "company, it and "fun guys"". This list of groups varies.

So basically, I am looking for all the lines after "Groups:" and before "Licenses:". Also do not want anything between the the brackets (for example, i want to remove `<company@domain.com>`)

[image]

Comment: To test this, you're expecting readers to type in the text in your screen shot.. Please update your question to include copy/paste of the text you want to search AND include your required output. (Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box). Finally include you current attempts with `grep` and current output and exact error messages. Good luck.

Comment: `grep` isn't good enough for this job (or maybe my grepping skill is not enough). Use `sed` to parse out the segment and do the line editing. To help you learn I won't give you final product; instead, I'll point you to a great sed tutorial: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

Comment: ...and add the expected output given that input. What we need you to provide is something we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **command** will do it,

```
sed -n '/Groups:/,/Licenses/p' sample |sed '1d'|sed '$d' |cut -f1 -d'<'
```

Here is **explanation**,

`sed -n '/Groups:/,/Licenses/p' sample`

Extracting text from the file sample in between two patterns as mentioned in regex above.

`sed '1d'` Deletes the line containing "Groups:" keyword.

`sed '$d'` Deletes the line containing "Licenses" keyword.

`cut -f1 -d'<'` Extracting the OPs mentioned patterns finally.

**Output:**

```
$ sed -n '/Groups:/,/Licenses/p' sample |sed '1d'|sed '$d' |cut -f1 -d'<'
        company 
        it 
        fun guys
```

Comment: Everything can be done with a single `sed` command. For range excluding the beginning and ending lines, see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a. As for the `cut`, the `sed` replacement should be obvious.

Comment: Skynet, that's spectacular!

Comment: thanks for appreciation @ZAMO